# Smooth character movement in Unity using the new Input System

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I’m currently working on a simple 2D character movement using the new Input System in Unity. I’m trying to add some smoothing to the character’s movement both in the air and on the ground, but it seems that the velocity is not changing smoothly. When I added some debug code, I noticed that the value of velocity.x is either 8 or -8 without any smoothing. I’ve tried using Mathf.SmoothDamp to achieve this effect, but it’s not working. Is there any other way to achieve this? Here’s my code for the movement function

```
private void Movement(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    Vector2 input = _inputAction.Player.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>();

    if (context.performed)
    {
        if (input != Vector2.zero)
        {
            Debug.Log("context.performed: " + context.performed);

            _velocity.x += input.x * _playerDetails.Acceleration;

            if (Mathf.Abs(_velocity.x) > _playerDetails.MoveClamp)
            {
                _velocity.x = input.x * _playerDetails.MoveClamp;
            }

            float targetVelocityX = _velocity.x * _playerDetails.Acceleration * Time.deltaTime;
            _velocity.x = Mathf.SmoothDamp(_velocity.x, targetVelocityX, ref _velocityXSmoothing, (_controller.CollisionInfos.Below) ? _playerDetails.AccelerationTimeGrounded : _playerDetails.AccelerationTimeAirborne);
        }
        else
        {
            _velocity.x = 0;
        }
    }

    //float targetVelocityX = input.x * _playerDetails.MoveClamp;
    //_velocity.x = Mathf.SmoothDamp(_velocity.x, targetVelocityX, ref _velocityXSmoothing, (_controller.CollisionInfos.Below) ? _playerDetails.AccelerationTimeGrounded : _playerDetails.AccelerationTimeAirborne);

    Debug.Log("_velocity.x: " + _velocity.x);

    _velocity.y += _gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    _controller.Move(_velocity * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could make a local variable for the target velocity, and then move the `_velocity` towards that target velocity in `Update`. This way you can have more freedom of design on the velocity-change speed and whatnot.

- [Vector3.MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html)

Comment: There is no need for an additional variable/field ... you already have `input` and `_velocity` so you can simply do `_velocity.x = Mathf.Clamp(Mathf.MoveTowards(_velocity.x, _velocity.x + input.x * _playerDetails.Acceleration, HOWFASTTOADAPT * Time.deltaTime), 0, _playerDetails.MoveClamp);`

Comment: `input` is a local variable inside the `Movement` method. you can't access it in `Update`

Comment: I tried to implement it as he suggested by removing the Movement function and implementing it directly in Update, but it’s still the same. I think I’ll use the old input system until I figure it out, hopefully

Comment: What I mean is .. you do not require `Update` for this necessarily .. depends how your InputActions are configured the `Movement` method itself can already be called once a frame .. or you go for Update and `GetValue` then you don't need this `Movement` method at all but have eveyrthing directly in Update already

Comment: @derHugo you're right, if the `Movement` is called every frame, then one could resolve the smooth transition right there  I told them to use Update just for simplicity of it.

Comment: @alimahdi I didn't mean deleting the `Movement` method. I meant saving the `_inputAction.Player.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>()` from that method to a local variable, say, `_targetVelocity`, and then in `Update` you could do `_velocity = Vector3.MoveTowards(_velocity, _targetVelocity, velocityChange * Time.deltaTime);` where `velocityChange` will be the change rate of your velocity input. 
and then `_controller.Move(_velocity * Time.deltaTime);` afterwards

Answer (score 0):

What you tried is using the `targetVelocity` but **after** already having modified the `_velocity`

Assuming that `Movement` is called once a frame even if the input value isn't changed you could do something like

```
private void Movement(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    var input = _inputAction.Player.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    
    if (input != Vector2.zero)
    {
        var targetVelocityX = _velocity.x + input.x * _playerDetails.Acceleration * Time.deltaTime;
        targetVelocityX = Mathf.Clamp(targetVelocityX, 0, _playerDetails.MoveClamp);
           
        _velocity.x = Mathf.SmoothDamp(_velocity.x, targetVelocityX, ref _velocityXSmoothing, (_controller.CollisionInfos.Below) ? _playerDetails.AccelerationTimeGrounded : _playerDetails.AccelerationTimeAirborne);  
    }
    else
    {
        _velocity.x = 0;
    }

    _velocity.y += _gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    Debug.Log($"_velocity.x: {}" + _velocity.x);
    _controller.Move(_velocity * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

This will still immediately stop though in `_velocity.x = 0;`

If you also wanted to smooth out the stopping you could move the `SmoothDamp` further own and do e.g.

```
private void Movement(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    var input = _inputAction.Player.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    var targetVelocityX = _velocity.x;        

    if (input != Vector2.zero)
    {
        targetVelocityX += input.x * _playerDetails.Acceleration * Time.deltaTime;
        targetVelocityX = Mathf.Clamp(targetVelocityX, 0, _playerDetails.MoveClamp); 
    }
    else
    {
        targetVelocityX = 0;
    }

    _velocity.x = Mathf.SmoothDamp(_velocity.x, targetVelocityX, ref _velocityXSmoothing, (_controller.CollisionInfos.Below) ? _playerDetails.AccelerationTimeGrounded : _playerDetails.AccelerationTimeAirborne);

    _velocity.y += _gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    Debug.Log($"_velocity.x: {}" + _velocity.x);
    _controller.Move(_velocity * Time.deltaTime);
}
```